# unicode printing python 2 vs python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, unicode, python-2.x

I ran the below commands in Python 2 and Python 3 with default encoding set to utf-8. 
In Python 2

```
x = u"\u2013"
print(x)
â
```

In python 3

```
x = u"\u2013"
print(x)
-
```

I am using python2. How can I print dash in this case?

Comment: Are you on Windows?  How did you set the encoding to UTF-8?  If you used `setdefaultencoding` and the `reload` trick, that's the wrong way to do it.  The Python 2 answer is OS-specific, and the real answer is use Python 3 since Python 2 is EOL.

Comment: Yes I used reload and setdefaultencoding. I am using unix machine which has python2.7. I know python 2 is not supported but I need to use it for the project I have.

Comment: All that does is force output to be UTF-8, but your terminal isn't configured for UTF-8.  `setdefaultencoding` is disabled for a reason.  Configure the terminal correctly (`LANG=en_US.UTF-8` I believe, but I'm on Windows) and it should work properly. `â` and two unprintable characters are what you get when you write UTF-8 to the terminal but it expects `ISO-8859-1` a.k.a `latin-1`.

Comment: Also, Unicode U+2013 isn't a code point supported by ISO-8859-1 which is probably why you went down the `reload` path.

Comment: It is already configured to the above LANG. It still outputs same a hat character.

Comment: If `LANG` has no effect, try setting `PYTHONIOENCODING`. Also, you'll want to make sure your terminal emulator (the app running the terminal) is expecting UTF-8; check the settings.